# Print/extract changelog.md specific sections, make code case insensitive

Tags: bash, shell, awk, changelog

Till now I've written

```
awk 's{ print ""; print}; $0~v {print; s=1; next}; s=0' RS= v=4.0.74 Chnagelog.md
```

This works awesome but now, I've a doubt. If I want to use case insensitive file name. Suppose instead of giving filename in lower, one have written the filename in all uppercase or camelcase then this script will not work.
How to modify this awk script to take case insensitive file names?

Comment: Could you please confirm if you are talking about only 1 file `Chnagelog.md` OR there could be multiple files to be passed to `awk`?

Comment: Only one file should be passed

Answer (score 2):

Most operating systems treat filenames case-sensitively and the difference in filenames
are regarded as different files. If you are sure about that, please try a combination with `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.md; do
    if [[ ${f,,} = "changelog.md" ]]; then
        awk 's{ print ""; print}; $0~v {print; s=1; next}; s=0' RS= v=4.0.74 "$f"
    fi
done
```

I suppose the better solution will be to fix the filename anyway.

Comment: I'm getting, for f in *.md; do. SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Are you sure you are executing the script with `bash`?

Comment: Yes. And do you know how to import shell script file in python. Basically how to import.

Comment: If you are working with bash, I have no idea why it causes an error as you mention. The syntax  `for f in *.md; do ... done` has been supported since very old `bash` including `sh`.

Comment: M ussing windows

Comment: If you are working with `Windows Subsystem for Linux`, try to execute `bash --version` on the terminal to see the response. If it returns an error, you may be working on Windows command prompt or other Windows shell, not `bash`.

Comment: It would be very helpful for me if you could provide more information such as the response to the command, your trial and approach etc. instead of yes/no answer. Judging from the comments in the other answer, I'm afraid you may not be working on the environment which we expect from your tag.

Comment: One possibility is that you created the script file with a Windows native
text editor and the file contains Windows line endings (CR+LF or 0x0d+0x0a)
while Unix/Linux tools expect line endings to be LF or 0x0a only.
Then please try to apply [dos2unix](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix/)
tool on your script file, then run the script again.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to utilise grep -i within awk:

```
awk -v v="4.0.74" '{ 
        while ("ls *.md | grep -i chnagelog.md" | getline fil) { # Run the ls/grep command, reading each result into the variable fil
          while (getline var1 < fil) { # Read each line of fil into the variable var1
            # Run initial awk code, processing var1 for $0
            if (var1 ~ v) { 
             print var1 
            } 
            else { 
             print "";
             print var1 
            }
          } 
          close(fil) # Close the opened file
         } 
         close("ls *.md | grep -i chnagelog") # Close the open pipe
        }' <<< /dev/null
```

Comment: Getting invalid syntax at -v v="1.0.12"

Comment: What version of awk are you running (awk -V) What OS are you are? Are you using bash?

Comment: Currently m using windows. IDE:- IntelliJ

Comment: Pussing the changes and seeing the output in pipeline of giblab